# How to recognize digits in Vuforia for Android development?

Tags: vuforia

I 'am currently developing an android application which is based on the Vuforia text recognition feature.but it dosen't recognize the digits.can anyone tell me how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default vuforia doesn't support digit recognition. But there might be workarounds or other approaches you might be able to use.